# Prove $ 1 \lt \int_0^1 \frac{1+x^{30}}{1+x^{60}} \ \mathrm{d}x \lt 1 + \frac{1}{30}$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, estimation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to prove $\int_0^1 \frac{1+x^{30}}{1+x^{60}} dx = 1 + \frac{c}{31}$, where $0 \lt c \lt 1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/128135/how-to-prove-int-01-frac1x301x60-dx-1-fracc31-where)

How can I prove the estimate $$ 1 \lt \int_0^1 \frac{1+x^{30}}{1+x^{60}} \ \mathrm{d}x \lt 1 + \frac{1}{30}?$$ Of course, the lower bound is pretty obvious. I realize this looks like a homework problem, but it's not (it's actually an old qualifying exam question). I think it is possible to use contour integration in the complex plane to get an exact expression for the integral, but this is pretty complicated and hopefully there is a way to estimate the integral without evaluating it.

Comment: See [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/128135/how-to-prove-int-01-frac1x301x60-dx-1-fracc31-where).

Comment: Oops, I didn't see the duplicate. I'm voting to close as well.

Answer (score 6):

$$1 < \dfrac{1+x^{30}}{1+x^{60}} < 1+x^{30} \,\,\,\,\, \forall x \in (0,1)$$

Comment: I think this is the best way one may think of. (+1)