# Integration using Taylor approximations

Tags: calculus, integration, taylor-expansion

I am stuck on two problems:

1) Prove that $$\int_0^1 \frac{1+x^{30}}{1+x^{60}}dx=1+\frac{c}{31}$$ 
where $0< c <1$.

2) Prove that $$0.493948<\int_0^{\frac{1}{2}}\frac{1}{1+x^4}dx<0.493958$$

Now for the first one I get Taylor expansion at $0$: $$\frac{1+x^{30}}{1+x^{60}}=1+E_0(x)$$ 
where $E_0(x)$ is the remainder. I suppose I need to use Lagrangian form of remainder, by differentianting the function and evaluating it at $c$ but I can't make any progress as the derivative is too clumsy.

For the second again I do not know how to incorporate the remainder in bounding the integral.

Hints are appreciated!

**Edit**

Considering the second problem, I just need help on bounding the remainder of Taylor expansion. I get:

$$\frac{1}{1+x^4}=1-x^4+x^8-x^{12}+x^{16}-Remainder$$

How do I specify bound for the remainder?

Comment: The first part is a [duplicate](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/128135/how-to-prove-int-01-frac1x301x60-dx-1-fracc31-where). An approach using power series expansions appears in an answer there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first one, since $x \in (0,1)$ we have $1 < 1+x^{60} < 1 + x^{30}$. Hence, we get that
$$1 < \dfrac{1+x^{30}}{1+x^{60}} < 1+x^{30}$$ Now you can get the answer.

For the second one, we have $$\dfrac1{1+x^4} = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(-x^4)^{k}$$
and hence
$$\sum_{k=0}^{2n+1}(-x^4)^{k} < \dfrac1{1+x^4} < \sum_{k=0}^{2n}(-x^4)^{k}$$
Take $n=2$ to get what you want.

Comment: note to myself - think out of the box. this way is indeed a simple one. but could I solve it using taylor expansion? if so, how?

Comment: @Sarunas What I have written is the first few terms in the Taylor expansion.

Comment: @Sarunas: If you mean Taylor series for 1), note that the Taylor series for $\frac{1+x}{1+x^2} = 1+x-x^2+x^3\cdots$. If $x \in [0,1)$, you have $\frac{1+x}{1+x^2} \leq 1+x$. Now replace $x$ by $x^{30}$ and you have Marvis' estimate.

Comment: oh right! just brilliant! now the second problem... :)